# TypeError: sentiment_analysis() missing 1 required positional argument: 'polarity'?

Tags: python, nlp, textblob

def sentiment_analysis(polarity):

```
if x < 0:
    print("neg")
elif x >0:
        print("pos")
else:
            print("neutral")


    
#analysis the text sentiment
text = processed_file.get('1.0',tk.END)
new_text = TextBlob(text)
processed_text = new_text.sentiment
result = '\nSubjectivity:{}, Polarity
                {}'.format(new_text.sentiment.subjectivity,new_text.sentiment.polarity)
x= result.sentiment.polarity
return sentiment_analysis(x)
show.insert(tk.END,x)
```

## Can someone explain why I am getting an typeerror

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here: `x= result.sentiment.polarity`

`result` isn't a `TextBlob` object, it's a string, and so you can't treat it as a `TextBlob` object: it doesn't know what to do.

If you replace the line `x= result.sentiment.polarity` with `x = processed_text.polarity`, then `x` is assigned the correct value. `processed_text` is a dictionary of sentiment scores from your `TextBlob` object.